# How do I properly type navigation guards in Nuxt class components?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt class component with Typescript and a `beforeRouteLeave` hook like this:

```js
import { Component, Vue } from "nuxt-property-decorator"

@Component
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  beforeRouteLeave (_to, _from, next) {
    this.foo()
    next()
  }

  foo () { console.log("navigation guard triggered") }
}
```

This throws TS errors because `_to, _from, next implicitly have an any type`. So I tried typing the method as a Vue Router `NavigationGuard` like this:

```js
import { Component, Vue } from "nuxt-property-decorator"
import type { NavigationGuard } from "vue-router"

@Component
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  beforeRouteLeave: NavigationGuard = function (this: MyComponent, to, _from, next) { // without typing `this` the next line throws an error
    this.foo()
    next()
  }

  foo () { console.log("navigation guard triggered") }
}
```

The TS errors are gone but the hook doesn't get triggered in the app. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should register the registerHooks lifeCycle in your custom plugin and register it in `nuxt.config.ts`.

```js
// plugin/main.ts
import 'vue-class-component/hooks' // auto registerHooks

// nuxt.config.ts
import type { NuxtConfig } from '@nuxt/types';
const config: NuxtConfig = {
     plugins: [ { src: '~/plugins/main.ts' } ]
     // ignore other...
};
export default config;
```

2. According to [doc](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards) the `beforeRouteLeave` have two or three parameter not four so just fix the code and it will work fine.

```js
// MyComponent.vue
import { Component, Vue } from "nuxt-property-decorator"
import { NavigationGuardNext, Route } from 'vue-router';

@Component
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {  
  beforeRouteLeave(to: Route, from: Route, next: NavigationGuardNext) {
    // will call the foo() function
    this.foo()
    next()
  }

  foo () { console.log("navigation guard triggered") }
}
```

3. If your VSCode still showing missing the type, you can create the `shims-vue.d.ts` to help Typescript understand the type. Here is [doc](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/hooks-auto-complete.html).